# How can we pass File object from second activity to main activity and then convert that object to uri?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to pass file object from second activity which stores the image location after capture.
Activity2.java:

```
'SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.US);
File file = new File(getBatchDirectoryName(), mDateFormat.format(new Date())+ ".jpg");   
this file object needs to be passed to main activity

ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new 
ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();
imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, executor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback () {
@Override
    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Image Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String message = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("location", message));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            
    '
```

> MainActivity.java:

```
   ' private void openActivity2() {
intent to open Activity 2
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
getting file object and convert to uri
    Intent intent1=getIntent();
    String fp = intent.getStringExtra("location");
    image_uri = Uri.parse(fp);
    }  '
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("path", file.getAbsolutePath()); File file = new File(intent.getExtra("path"));

Comment: @blackapps this passes file from one activity to another?

Comment: This passes the value of file.getAbsolutePath() yes.

Comment: private void openActivity2() {
        //intent to open Activity 2
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        intent = getIntent();
        File file = new File(String.valueOf(intent.getStringArrayExtra("location")));
        //String fp = intent.getStringExtra("location");
        //image_uri = Uri.parse(fp);
    }

Comment: String message = file.getAbsolutePath();
                            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("location", message));
                            finish();

Comment: is it correct?..

Comment: Why do you ask me? Did it work?

Comment: You have never told that you started the second activity from the main activity and that at finisch of second activity that you wanna transfer some data to to caller and want to receive that data in onActivityResult() in main activity.

Comment: The Main Activity button initiates the second activity which captures a picture. The image is being captured and saved. But I'm unable to display it in main activity. I need the uri from second activity. Could you help me out, please?

Comment: Before you would display it in MainActivity you would first receive the file path in onActivityResult(). Where is your code doing that???

Comment: In second activity I'm getting the file path, when the image is captured and saved. I need it in the main activity.

Comment: `startActivity(intent);` You should use startActivityForResult() instead. In order to receive that path in onActivityResult(). I named onActivityResult() before but you managed to not even to react on it. Are you the same one who had those friendly words for me lately?

Comment: I've tried using startActivityForResult(). The app is crashing.

Comment: Could you suggest anything to try?